# CSS on Wrap Clear All

Tags: css

I have an application with boxes. Big boxes are 300px by 300px, and small boxes are 150px by 150px. When a small box is clicked, it turns into a big box. The boxes are all styled as float:left, and are allowed to wrap when the window is resized.

Unfortunately, any small boxes that get wrapped end up to the right of the last big box in a line (as shown).

[image: Example of undesired wrapping]

1) How can I allow wrapping while making sure that wrapped boxes completely clear the line? (in my example, boxes 6 and 7 should be to the left of box 8).

2) Is there any way to make boxes 6 and 7 fill in the empty space under boxes 1 and 2, and then fill in the empty space below boxes 4 and 5 with box 8 and up?

Comment: This is impossible with pure CSS. You need a JS grid engine for this.

Comment: 1) `display: inline-block` might work better in this case than floating. 2) Not with CSS alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As Matt suggested in the comments, use `inline-block`. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/izonux/1/edit)
2. Has been asked [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=masonry%20isotope%20is:answer) and it's not possible in CSS. Check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for a JS solution.